# Toad dont return me the time

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, toad

I got a problem with my date conversion , when I do this part of code , it return me only the date without the time :

```
DECLARE
        vdate VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN  
        select cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2020-09-23T03:02:00+02:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"+"TZH:TZM') as date) into vdate from dual; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vdate);
END;
```

This return me only :

```
23-SEP-20
```

How can I do to get date and hours ? Thanks

Comment: @Abra I have try but I got "INVALID NUMBER" Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DECLARE
  vdate VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN  
  select cast(
           TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
             '2020-09-23T03:02:00+02:00',
             'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM' -- remove the "+"
           )
           as date
         )
  into   vdate
  from   dual;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vdate);
END;
/
```

You go from a string (`2020-09-23T03:02:00+02:00`) to a timestamp (using the `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function, and you shouldn't explicitly match the `+` character and should, instead, let the `TZH` format model match it) then to a date and then you put it into a string variable which requires an implicit conversion from the binary date value to a string. This all seems overkill. However, it is this last step, the implicit conversion from date to string, that is causing your issue as Oracle will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model to do the conversion.

One method of solving this is to use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';
```

and then your code should output the correct value without having to change your code.

However, you **should not** use this method as it relies on the user changing their session and most users aren't going to do that (and if they do then they are just as likely to change it to a date format that they prefer than to the one you want which would, again, break your expectations for the code's behaviour).

Instead, if you want a specific format or a date then you should explicitly apply the format using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
BEGIN  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    TO_CHAR(
      TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
        '2020-09-23T03:02:00+02:00',
        'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'
      ),
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
    )
  );
END;
/
```

*(Note: you don't need to: declare a variable; to use SQL; or to convert to a date. Instead you can do it all in the one line.)*

If you did want to use a variable then you can do it all in PL/SQL by assigning the value directly to the variable (and don't need to context-switch to use the SQL engine):

```sql
DECLARE
  vdate DATE;
BEGIN
  vdate := TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
             '2020-09-23T03:02:00+02:00',
             'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM'
           );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR( vdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' ) );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8170fcd7cf00903b408356d566cd8ca7)*

Comment: Thanks but this solution doesent work for me , I need a result like this  : 23-SEPT.-20 03:02:00 , and when I convert you'r result with  TO_DATE(vdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); I got only date whitout time

Comment: @MySqlDev788 In my last example, `vdate` is already a `DATE` type; you don't need to (and should not) use `TO_DATE` on it. I you want a specific format string then use the appropriate [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-FC63D86D-EB36-4A19-995E-C3C146747DF4) with `TO_CHAR` such as `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( TO_CHAR( vdate, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS' ) );`.

Comment: I need to convert it to date beacause I make update in my table in a DATE Column

Comment: @MySqlDev788 `vdate` is declared as a `DATE` data type. Using `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` gives you a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and then assigning it to the `vdate` variable then Oracle will implicitly cast it to a `DATE`. You do not need to do anything else as `vdate` is already a `DATE` .... just use its value and insert it into the table without any further conversions (unless you need to convert to a standard time zone such as UTC+0).

Answer (score 0):

In Toad, you can set the Date format mask under **View -> Toad Options**. My screenshot is from Toad 13.2.0.258.

[image]